# Orthogonal basis for this inner product

Tags: vectors

$$ \text{ In }\mathbb R^2, \langle u,v\rangle = 2u_1v_1 - u_1v_2 - v_1u_2 + u_2v_2$$

what is the orthogonal basis, I have no idea how to go about this question?

Comment: sorry it was meant to be equal to <u,v>

Comment: I mean the inner space product of u,v in R^2

Comment: Ok. By the way, you may wish to have a look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) question on meta to learn how to typeset math here. Welcome to MSE!

Comment: I still don't get your question... do you want an orthogonal basis with respect to the given inner product?

Comment: Yes thats what Im looking for

Comment: there is not one orthogonal basis. there are many. take any orthogonal basis and rotate or reflect, you get another orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pick one vector as $(1,0).$ now you can project $(0,1)$ onto this and subtract to get an orthogonal vector. here is how you do this. $$(0,1) = k(1,0) + (e_1, e_2) $$ we require of $k$ so that $e$ is orthogonal to $(1,0).$  that is

$$ -1 = \langle<(0,1), (1,0)\rangle = k\langle (1, 0), (1,0)\rangle = k \times 2 $$

that is $$k = -\frac 12, (e_1, e_2) = (0,1) + \frac 12(1,0)=\left(\frac 12, 1\right)  $$

an orthogonal basis is $$\{(1,0), \left(1, 2\right)    \} $$

Comment: @Bye_World, i corrected it. check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Choose one vector arbitrarily, for example $(1,0)$. Then apply Gram Schmidt to extend this to an orthogonal basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Choose one vector arbitrarily, for example $(1,0)$. Then plug it into your formula for the inner product $$\langle (1,0),\mathbf v\rangle = 2v_1 - v_2$$ and then choose *any* two numbers $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that this equals $0$ (except obviously $v_1=v_2=0$).

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand why this works, so the basis would be {1,2}?

Comment: No, the basis would be $\{(1,0), (1,2)\}$.  The definition of orthogonality is $\langle \mathbf u, \mathbf v\rangle = 0$.  I just plugged in the $\mathbf u$.

Comment: @GGWP This is equivalent to Gram Schmidt.